# Shortcuts for VisualStudio Online

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In jira to add a comment we used the C letter as a shortcut. What are the shortcuts in visual studio online task board.

It takes too much time to go to the discussions part and add something there.

[image]

Comment: Woooow that is not a shortcut. At Jira be on the task press C than add the comment you are done.... Thats a shortcut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think VSTS has a specific shortcut to go to the discussion section.

You can see all the available shortcuts here

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: this is the answer to the shortcuts. Still could not find a practical way to add comments to VSTS Cloud service which I frequently use.

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

I think you should submit this request. Seems useful